# Heuristic Arguments against Existence of very inefficient alogirthm for SAT

Tags: satisfiability

I am reading the [Handbook of Satisfiability](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=shLvAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=backtrack%20non-chronologically&source=bl&ots=n68kr0Iwzw&sig=dUUiJT1qrDsMl8d7Ga1bA-decoI&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbtJSepPXKAhWGDpAKHSxxCAkQ6AEIVTAI#v=onepage&q=backtrack%20non-chronologically&f=false) and in the preface Martin Davis wrote

> Of course what is regarded as the most important problem in theoretical computer science, P = ? NP lives right here. It is remarkable that we still don’t know whether or not there is a poly-time algorithm for SAT. I am in a tiny minority in being unconvinced that the answer must be “No”. I surely don’t expect anyone to find a really efficient uniform algorithm for SAT. But I find **the heuristic arguments against the existence of a very inefficient algorithm for SAT that happens to run in poly-time** quite unconvincing.

The part in bold I do not understand, Could you help me to desccribe who are the heuristic arguments against the existence of a very inefficient algorithm for SAT that happens to run in poly-time?

Comment: I think he's saying that the heuristic arguments that there's no, say, $O(n^{1000})$ algorithm for SAT aren't convincing.  (Such an algorithm is in **P** but can't really be described as "efficient".)

Comment: @DavidRicherby. So what would be an example of such a heuristic argument?